# jquery - get sum from dynamicaly created elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sum

I am building a form to calculate the sum of some services. The user must input the net amount and the vat amount(%) and then the program should calculate the total amount and the total vat amount. Each time one of the input fields is changed it should automatically update the total and vat total box. Also the user can insert multiple rows (same classes, unique ids) and these must be sum up as well! this is what i did so far [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/bn4na8qc/).

with the code below I managed to calculate the 1rst row only and if i insert `.each()` so it will calculate each element in the code then it doesn't work! and there are no errors! Shouldn't each return all the values specified in its element?

```
$('#sig_3').on('change','.vat_calc',function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var id_suffix_new = id.split('_').pop();
    var amount_val = parseFloat($('#amount_'+id_suffix_new).val());
    var vat_val = parseFloat($('#vat_'+id_suffix_new).val());
    var vat_amount = amount_val * vat_val;
    $('#vat_amount_'+id_suffix_new).val( parseFloat(vat_amount));
    total = amount_val+vat_amount;
    $('#total').val(parseFloat(total));
});
```

Comment: Ids have to be **unique** and the question should include all code necessary to verify the problem -> [How to create a minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: ids **ARE** unique as I already wrote above. The complete code is **IN** the fiddle. @Andreas

Comment: this question might give you some ideas https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44894550/calculating-values-in-dynamically-created-dom/44894979#44894979

Comment: @taha thanks, but i already saw that.. wasn't much help! I need something simpler and more readable "/

Comment: The code in the fiddle is not the same as the one in the question. [`.val()`](https://api.jquery.com/val/) returns the value of the _first_ element in the set of matched elements

Comment: @Andreas the code in the fiddle includes the `.each()` which shows that it doesn't work! quoting the above link **you** provided:  >…Verifiable – Test the code you're about to provide to make sure it reproduces the problem

Comment: The code in the fiddle selects the elements via class which will return a set of elements. And as already written, `.val()` only returns the value of the _first_ element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have updated your fiddle, here is the Link -
 https://jsfiddle.net/bn4na8qc/3/

```js
    $('ul').each(function() {
    var amount_val = parseFloat($(this).find('.amount').val());
    var vat_val = parseFloat($(this).find('.vat_calc').val());
    var vat_amount = amount_val * vat_val;
        $(this).find('.vat_amount').val(parseFloat(vat_amount));
        total_vat += parseFloat(vat_amount);
        total += amount_val + vat_amount;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add value of dynamic inputs this way:

```js
$("#add").click(function(){
    $("#content").append("<input type='text' value=0 class='data' />");
})

$(document).on('change',".data",function(){
    var total = 0;
    $(".data").each(function(){
      total += parseFloat($(this).val());
    })
    $("#total").html(total);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
  <div id="content">
    
  </div>
  <div id="total" style="width=100px;height:20px;background-color:#cbcbcb">
      
  </div>
  <button id="add" style="width:100px;height:20px">Add Input</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No I need a function that every time the vat_calc changes it will sum everything up! just that I cant change the whole code